# Docker: ssh -L to docker container - connection refused

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile, docker-swarm, ssh-tunnel

I'm having problems to get my ssh tunnel working for my container in a docker swarm cluster.

ssh connection on my local machine:

```
ssh -L 7180:test.XXX:7180 user@XXX
```

In my Dockerfile on the remote machine:

```
EXPOSE 7180
```

Container start:

```
docker -H test:2379 --tlsverify run -d -p 7180:7180 --net=my-net
```

I tried to connect in Firefox via:

```
localhost:7180
```

Unfortunately the connection gets refused on the remote machine:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

"docker container ls" prints following for the ports:

```
xxx:7180->7180/tcp
```

Inside my container "netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN" prints:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7180            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I'm new to this but after all what I've read so far this should actually work. I'm using "--net=my-net" because I want to setup my own network later. I had the same issue with "--net=host". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your server is XXX, can you test:  `ssh -L 7180:localhost:7180 user@XXX` ?

Comment: This results in the same error message.

Comment: I get the same error when I use dynamic port forwarding:
ssh -D localhost:7180 -f -C -q -N user@XXX. I configured Firefox with the v5 proxy in this case.

Comment: On your server, can you do a `netstat -ntlp | grep 7180`

Comment: I get: (No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=9023 but you should be root.) I'm not a root user on this host, I'm only in the docker group.

Answer (score 1):

The ssh command should be:

```
ssh -L 7180:127.0.0.1:7180 user@XXX
```

And then from your browser, you would go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7180
```

I've avoided using "localhost" because some machines map this to IPv6 even if you don't have IPv6 configured.

When testing this tunnel, make sure your application is listening on the remote server by doing an `ssh` to that server and run a `curl` command directly on the server to 127.0.0.1:7180`. If it doesn't work there, you would repeat your debugging with netstat inside the container and verifying the port is published in the`docker ps` output.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with

```
ssh -D localhost:7180 -f -C -q -N user@XXX
```

and using

```
xxx:7180
```

in my browser (instead of localhost).
localhost and --net=host did not work for me with ssh -L.

Comment: If your browser is going to `xxx:7180`, are you going over the ssh tunnel at all? Seems like you just went directly to the host without the tunnel.